# Unicode character's are not working in java when i m storing values in String query for jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, unicode

String query =  "select * from table where word='سیب'";

unicodes works fine in java but not fetching values from database 
i don't know what's the problem :(

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check if your database configuration is supporting UTF-16.

What happens executing the query on a database client instead from java code?

Comment: No result's match after executing my query but i have stroed values in my database

Comment: Try to execute a select * without condition and check what value was saved on the field 'word'

Comment: well Thanks @David Lorenzo MARINO for giving me suggestions 
 i have solved my problem

Comment: If you found that answer useful you can upvote it and flag it as the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that a given string is not matched in the database, even though you have the value stored. I believe your problem is as follows: you are using different character sets in your application from your database. You should either change the character set in one of those or you should convert the string into the character set used at the db before you run your query.